# How to access all querystring parameters as a dictionary

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I have some dynamic querystring parameters that I would like to interact with as an `IDictionary<string,string>`. How do I do this?

I tried

```
public IHttpActionResult Get(FromUri]IDictionary<string, string> selections)
```

[as suggested](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETWireFormatForModelBindingToArraysListsCollectionsDictionaries.aspx) but for a query of

```
/api/MyController?selections%5Bsub-category%5D=kellogs
```

it always gives me a dictionary with 0 items.

I don't even need the `selections` prefix. I literally just need all querystring parameters as a dictionary. How do I do this and why won't the above work?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

You can use the [`GetQueryNameValuePairs` extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httprequestmessageextensions.getquerynamevaluepairs%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) on the `HttpRequestMessage` to get the parsed query string as a collection of key-value pairs.

```cs
public IHttpActionResult Get()
{
    var queryString = this.Request.GetQueryNameValuePairs();
}
```

And you can create some further extension methods to make it eaiser to work with as described here: [WebAPI: Getting Headers, QueryString and Cookie Values](http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2013/Apr/15/WebAPI-Getting-Headers-QueryString-and-Cookie-Values)

```cs
/// <summary>
/// Extends the HttpRequestMessage collection
/// </summary>
public static class HttpRequestMessageExtensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Returns a dictionary of QueryStrings that's easier to work with 
    /// than GetQueryNameValuePairs KevValuePairs collection.
    /// 
    /// If you need to pull a few single values use GetQueryString instead.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="request"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static Dictionary<string, string> GetQueryStrings(
        this HttpRequestMessage request)
    {
         return request.GetQueryNameValuePairs()
                       .ToDictionary(kv => kv.Key, kv=> kv.Value, 
                            StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
    }
}
```

Comment: There's an interesting comment on that web page post though which is that "This will throw an exception for duplicate key, if a query parameter is repeated".  Note that repeated querystring keys is perfectly valid URL syntax.

Comment: If the querystring contains an encoded & (ampersand), like this: `?key=value1%26value2%26value3` then the keys get "split" at the & character (you end up with 3 dictionary entries instead of 1). What's the reason for this?

Answer (score 2):

In addition to what nemesv mentioned, you can also create a custom parameter binding for `IDictionary<string,string>` similar to the approach I show here:

[How would I create a model binder to bind an int array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22410085/how-would-i-create-a-model-binder-to-bind-an-int-array/22411989#22411989)

Answer (score 1):

We can use `HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(<string>)` method from `System.Web` namespace. This method will parse the query string given as input and return it as an `NameValueCollection`.