# OData (create custom) query option

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, odata

i need to create a custom query option and to be honest i have no idea where to start from. i don't know how they are created or what class handles them. 
On my project i have used markdown but i also need to enable ( in which case the text marked will be markdown ) or disable ( in this case i will have plain text ).

at this point my solution was to send a parameter to a function and tell it when to enable / disable

EX:

> .../.../Namespace.MyFunction(markdown=1)

but i'm looking for a way to obtain this

> .../.../...?$markdown=true

something like count query option.

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The dollar sign  prefix should only be used with system query options. Think of `$` as a reserved namespace. You can certainly use your own application-specific query options; just don't prefix them with `$`.

To get the value of `markdown` from a request URI like `http://host/path?markdown=true` from within a controller method, use the [`GetQueryNameValuePairs`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httprequestmessageextensions.getquerynamevaluepairs(v=vs.118).aspx) extension method. See also [How to access all querystring parameters as a dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22419823/how-to-access-all-querystring-parameters-as-a-dictionary).

Answer (score 3):

Since you're using ASP.NET, you can also just use regular [parameter binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api).

For example, an `ODataController` action method with the following prototype:

```
[EnableQuery]
public IQueryable<MyEntity> Get(string testParam = "")
```

will service a request at the following URL:

```
http://your.machine/api/odata/myentity?$count=true&$top=10&$skip=0&testParam=true
```

The OData parameters `$count`, `$top`, and `$skip` will all be honored, and your custom `testParam` will have the string `"true"` assigned within the `Get` method.

Comment: Please note that it seems the order of the query parameters is important. If I place the custom query parameters at the beginning of the query, they end up being null and the ODataQueryOptions object also ends up invalid: `public IQueryable<MyEntity> Get(ODataQueryOptions<MyEntity> queryOptions, string testParam = "")`. In my case this worked: `http://your.machine/api/odata/myentity?$count=true&$top=10&$skip=0&testParam=true`; this didn't: `http://your.machine/api/odata/myentity?testParam=true&$count=true&$top=10&$skip=0`