# Return Object Based on Query Strings

Tags: c#, asp.net, reflection, .net-core

I'm trying to return objects based on query strings.
For example, I would like `api/users/{id}?fields=username,email,reputation` to return an object of type User that contains only the three included properties (username, email, reputation).

On a side note, comma separated query strings are not possible by default in .NET Core.
[Here's a tutorial on making that work](https://www.strathweb.com/2017/07/customizing-query-string-parameter-binding-in-asp-net-core-mvc/).

Following the guide above, I have a list of strings. How can I create an object that only includes the properties that match the names of those strings?
For only a few strings I can do this (thanks Ben Hall):

```
List<string> listOfStrings ...; // Strings from query
User user = GetUser(id); // User from db 

User newUser = new User();

if (listOfStrings.Contains("username"))
    newUser.username = user.username;
if (listOfStrings.Contains("email"))
    newUser.email = user.email;
if (listOfStrings.Contains("reputation"))
    newUser.reputation = user.reputation;
```

**But for a long list of strings (my user class has 30+ properties) how would I go about doing this?**

For reference, [Facebook Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api) does this.

Comment: you _could_ use reflection on the public properties of `typeof(user)` and only copy those fields from `user` to `newUser` that are named but ... why? for asp.net, simply do not display anything from the `user` thats not in the query string...

Comment: You can just return an anonymous object that has those proprties.

Comment: I was making a mistake with the if statement placement lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Turns out there is actually Middleware for this called Popcorn.](https://github.com/SkywardApps/popcorn/)

> Popcorn is a communication protocol on top of a RESTful API that allows requesting clients to identify individual fields of resources to include when retrieving the resource or resource collection.
>
> It allows for a recursive selection of fields, allowing multiple calls
>   to be condensed into one.
>
> **Features:**
>
> - Selective inclusion from a RESTful API
> - Configurable response defaults
> - Sorting of responses
> - Selective authorization and permissioning of response values
> - Configurable response inspectors
> - Factory and advanced projection support
> - Set relevant contexts for your API
> - Blind expansion f response objects

Answer (score 2):

```
List<string> listOfStrings ...; // Strings from query
User user = GetUser(id); // User from db 

User newUser = new User();
//gettting object type
var userType = user.GetType();
```

This solution needs some knowledge about Reflections 
 It uses the methods GetValue and SetValue 
(The code is tested in Visual Studio) 
Now foreach element in listOfStrings

```
foreach(var propertyName in listOfString){
// This line of code retrives the value of the propety in the user class
 var retrivedValue = userType.GetProperty(propertyName).GetValue(user);
// This line of code sets the value retrived to the property in the newUser class
 userType.GetProperty(propertyName).SetValue(newUser, retrivedValue , null);
}
```

Comment: This works, thank you. Although my goal was to return the newUser object anonymously (only including the properties that are given in the query). Is this possible?

Comment: Essentially i'd like to do exactly what the Facebook Graph API does. The returned JSON object should only contain the fields specified in the query.

Comment: I achieved this by creating a `IDictionary<string, object>`, checking for null inside the foreach and storing as `propertyName` key and `retreivedValue` value. I then return the dictionary which only includes the properties that were given and were not null. This doesn't use all of the code you wrote above but it was valuable to learn about nonetheless. Thank you again for your help :)

Comment: One other way is using Json.net [NullValueHandling-Enumeration](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_NullValueHandling.htm) returning just non null values from object.

Comment: Oh great! Thanks. AutoMapper also has null value handling :)

Answer (score 1):

We could explore other ways like reflection but `if` should still serve you well enough. Looks like you're making a simple mistake trying to use an `If` in an object initialiser. You will have to do that after instaniating the new User object e.g.

```
User newUser = new User();
if (listOfStrings.Contains("username"))
{
       newUser.username = user.username;
}
```

Comment: If my potential list of strings is long, how would this be best approached?

Comment: Getting into reflection territory. I've talked about [similar things](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40041905/web-api-handle-misspelled-fromuri-parameters/40043835#40043835) but not exactly this problem and can't say I have ever used a [string name to access a property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2905187/accessing-object-property-as-string-and-setting-its-value).