# Pass dynamic Parameters by rest URL to C# method with dynamic Parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net, post, asp.net-web-api, keyvaluepair

I want to pass dynamic Parameters by rest URL to C# method with dynamic Parameters.
For example, I want to call a rest URL like this:

```
http://localhost:2000/custom?**user=admin?password=admin?brand=dell&limit=20&price=20000&type1=laptop&type2=phone**
```

to a C# method of one dynamic parameter, the dynamic parameter takes "**user**" and its value "**admin**", "**brand**" and its value "**dell**" etc., and process them.

Can somebody help me please.

Comment: do not ever send passwords in URL. Either chuck it in the post or put it in the header if you use https only.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Web API with dynamic parameter, you need use it as POST method.

URL: `http://localhost:2000/custom`

Data:

```
{
user:"admin"
password:"admin",
brand:"dell",
limit:20
}
```

Comment: Yes, I used it as a post method, this request is rest webservice and the data must be in the URL

Comment: parameters can be passed in URL as well and read like a dictionary. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22419823/how-to-access-all-querystring-parameters-as-a-dictionary

Comment: how do I get a dictionary from "http://url/?a=1&b=2&c=3" 
the a and b and c will send to the param of type dictionary

I think this will solve my problem

Answer (score 0):

You can use `NameValueCollection` returned by `ParseQueryString` :

```
Uri myUri = new Uri("http://localhost:2000/custom?user=admin?password=admin?brand=dell&limit=20&price=20000&type1=laptop&type2=phone");
string user= HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(myUri.Query).Get("user");
string password= HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(myUri.Query).Get("password");
string brand= HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(myUri.Query).Get("brand");
string limit= HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(myUri.Query).Get("limit");
...
```

But passing the user:pass in GET and in plaintext is such a bad (**very bad**) idea :)